# How to set class on clicked element using Angular Renderer2

Tags: angular, angular-renderer2

i have an angular click event attached on span in my component's html

```
<span (click)="doWork($event)" > Something </span>
```

and in my component i want to perform some operation and than add a class to this span using renderer2's addClass method. I injected Renderer2 from constrctor and used it in function

```
doWork (e) {
  //some operations
  this.renderer.addClass( e.target, 'selected' );
}
```

but i am unable to attach class on span in this way, am i missing something?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a stackblitz ? I can't reproduce your issue, [it's working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kl5yal)

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this.

```
<span (click)="doWork()" id="sp_id"> Something </span> // You can use a class if you wish
```

Then in your constructor do this:

```
constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2) {
}

doWork() {
   const span_id = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#sp_id');
   this.renderer.addClass(span_id, 'spclass'); // spclass is the name of the class
}
```

That will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative implementation for your desired behavior is use `ngClass` and a flag for add/remove your custom class on clicked element directly in HTML.

HTML:

```
<span [ngClass]="classAddFlag ? 'spClass' : ''" (click)="doWork()" > Something </span>
```

Then in your `doWork()` function you only need to set properly the flag for show or hide your class.

TS:

```
// Set the flag as component variable
classAddFlag = false;

doWork (e) {
   //some operations
   this.classAddFlag = !this.classAddFlag;
}
```

Comment: this is the way